# Как преобразовать массив данных в pdf (React)?

Tags: reactjs

Ребята, подскажите как можно преобразовать массив данных в pdf. Логика такая - в функ.компонент залетает переменная companyList (БД из Firebase) в виде массиве. В данном компоненте есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую происходит "преобразование" массива с БД в обычный pdf-файл, который можно скачать. Как это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Генерация pdf происходит с помощью разных библиотек, их очень много можно найти в поисковике, например для  js такая: https://github.com/foliojs/pdfkit. Но имейте ввиду - большинство бесплатных библиотеки - pdf создают плохого качества (разрыв страницы происходит в случайном месте, посреди картинки например), потомунадо перебирать пробовать